# passing a class to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my problem statement:

I've an extractor class which calls a ConfigManager class and passes a type as an argument. Based on the type, ConfigManager resolves the class that needs to be called.

At this point, ConfigManager has a reference to the class.

However ConfigManager needs to pass this class back to the extractor.

ConfigManager is a helper class which the Extractor will call to get type specific class.

How do I make the ConfigManager pass the class to Extractor?

I'm new to python and any help is much appreciated.

```
Extractor -> ConfigManager -> AbstractLoader| -> Metric1Loader

Extractor class calls ConfigManager. ConfigManager gets Metric1Loader class and needs to pass it to Extractor.
```

ConfigManager should pass class reference of Metric1Loader back to Extractor.

Comment: I'm getting confused by your description - you mention Extractor calling ConfigManager, but then you mention Extractor calling the method that ConfigManager should be calling. Could you make a diagram or something to clear this up?

Comment: Let me try to explain. Extractor calls ConfigManager and it should get a class reference in return from ConfigManager.

Comment: I would just make a dictionary: `c_dict = {"Class1": Class1, "Class2":Class2, ...}` to correspond a string to the class to which it refers. Then, if given the string `ctype = "Class1"`, you could do `instance = c_dict[ctype]()` to construct an instance of `Class1`. And then return that.

Comment: Some code would help. You talk about using your classes like functions; are you doing anything with the *instances* that each class will return when called?

Comment: Yes, the extractor will be calling various methods in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps create a method that returns the data to the object that needs it?

```
def ConfigManager:
    def resolveClass(self, name):
        return obj

def Extractor:
    def doSomething(self):
        configManager = ConfigManager()
        resolvedClass = configManager.resolveClass("name")
```

Answer (score 2):

To me, your requirement sounds like a problem which can be solved by `factory` design pattern.

Here's an example which can be used as a reference.

```py
class AbstractLoader:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Metric1Loader(AbstractLoader):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Metric1Loader')


class Metric2Loader(AbstractLoader):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Metric2Loader')


class Factory:
    @staticmethod
    def make_class(target_class):
        # This will instantiate object of type determined from target_class string
        return globals()[target_class]()


def extractor():

    types = ['Metric1Loader', 'Metric2Loader']

    for type in types:
        obj = Factory.make_class(type)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractor()

# STDOUT:
# Metric1Loader
# Metric2Loader
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent example. Yes this is precisely what I'm doing to resolve the class. My original question was once I've the class, how do I pass it to the extractor class. The other comment seems to have answered my problem.